# Classify static/moving objects on a set of images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have to implement a basic tracking program in MATLAB that, given a set of frames from a videogame, it analyzes each one of them and then creates a bounding box around each object. I've used the function `regionprops` in order to obtain the coordinates of the bounding boxes for each object, and visualized them using the function `rectangle`, as follows:

```
for i = 1:size( frames,2 )
    CC{1,i} = findConnectedComponents( frames{1,i} );
    stats{1,i} = regionprops( 'struct',CC{1,i},'BoundingBox','Centroid' );
    imshow( frames{1,i} ),hold on
    for j = 1:size(stats{1,i},1)
        r = rectangle( 'Position',stats{1,i}(j).BoundingBox );
        r.FaceColor = [0 0.5 0.5 0.45];
    end
end
```

This works just fine, but I'd like to go one step further and be able to differenciate static objects from moving objects. I thought of using the centroid to see, for each object, if it is different in each frame (which would mean that the object is moving), but in each image I have a different number of objects.

For example, if I am trying this on Space Invaders, when you kill an alien it disappears, so the number of objects is reduced. Also each projectile is a separate object and there could be a different number of projectiles in different moments of the game.

So my question is, how could I classify the objects based on wether they move or not, and paint them with two different colors?

Comment: You will somehow have to combine spatial and temporal information of objects and cancel the motion vector against the camera movement across frames to find out which objects actually moved within frames in a video. This an active research topic. 
This should be a good start : http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~katef/papers/CVPR2015_LearnVideoSegment.pdf

Comment: The good thing about my problem is that there is no camera movement. It's all on Atari games, very simple games, like PacMan or Space Invaders, in which only some objects move around the screen and the others stay static. I just need to "separate" them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of consistent background, using [optical flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow) is ideal for you.

The basic idea is pretty simple, consider subtracting two consecutive frames, and use this to get flow vector of the objects that moved between frames.

You can look at [Lucas–Kanade method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method)
and [Horn–Schunck method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn%E2%80%93Schunck_method).

[Here is a link](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/optical-flow.html) for matlab implementation of the same.

Comment: Oh yes, I thought of optical flow of course, but sadly I cannot use the computer vision toolbox for this project, and I should be able to do it with bounding boxes...

Comment: You can find the flow vector on your own and then use `regionprops`.

Comment: Yes but how? This is my main problem... How to combine these techniques into being able to visualize the frame with green bounding boxes around the static objects and red bounding boxes around the moving objects...

Comment: you get a bounding box around each object using regionprops for first image. Now in the next frame look for all the objects detected before in a small region around each object's original location. This is because the moving object's position would have changed only slightly in consecutive frames while static objects will still be in their same location. Now you can easily make bounding boxes around moving objects